# Deploy via firebase-tools API without previous login

Tags: firebase, oauth, google-oauth, firebase-cli

I'm currently building an open-source microservice that makes use of Firebase Database, Hosting & Functions. The plan is to pack everything in a single binary and distribute this. So users will have a hazzle-free, "bring your own Firebase project"-solution. They'll just have to download the binary and their Firebase secret key and can then create a user and deploy the service via CLI.

The problem is, that firebase-tools require a `$FIREBASE_TOKEN` when deploying via its API. So users would have to install firebase-tools in order to be able to generate that token and they would also have to store it (or re-generate it frequently).

Since I would like to provide a hazzle-free experience, I'd rather generate that token myself with the help of the secret key.

The question is: is this even possible? And if yes: how??

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this is to reflect the login- and logout-commands of the Firebase-CLI on my own binary's CLI. So the user won't have to install another tool.

To get the refresh_token I then read the data from the firebase-tools-configstore, that is located in the user folder. This feels a little dirty, like accessing a private API. But I couldn't come up with a better solution. And it works.